# Need advice in enum design structure in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have an enum which is quite weird for me.

```
enum PoolType {

    FIXED(4),
    CACHED,
    SINGLE;

    private int threadsAmount;

    private PoolType(int threadsAmount) {
        this.threadsAmount = threadsAmount;
    }

    private PoolType() {
    }

    public int getThreadsAmount() {
        return threadsAmount;
    }

    public PoolType withThreads(int threadsAmount) {
        this.threadsAmount = threadsAmount;
        return this;                    
    }
}
```

Actually I want to know is it OK by design or maybe there are some errors?

*PS*

I cau use it in a way like this

```
new ExecutionStarter(PoolType.CACHED.withThreads(5));
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why put this is SO instead of Code Review?

Comment: An enum is immutable, if you call two times to `#withTreads` it will modify the first enum, so this is not a good case for a enum.

Comment: Enums *should* be immutable - this one isn't. It's unclear why you're using an enum here at all.

Comment: A `withFoo` method normally returns a new instance of an immutable object. Of course, that's not possible with enums. So, on top of the problem of mutable enums (very bad), you also have a misleading method name (also bad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to modify the number of threads, you'll need two classes.

A Pool which can have it's threads configured, and a PoolType which can be an enum.

Since the enum only provides type handling, you are much better off ditching the type delegation via an enum pattern.  Instead use the Java type system directly

```
public interface Pool ...
public class FixedPool implements Pool ...
... etc ...
```

This way you can have two fixed pools of different thread sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Enums should be immutable. Yours isn't:

```
PoolType.CACHED.withThreads(5);
System.out.println(PoolType.CACHED.getThreadsAmount()); // Prints 5

PoolType.CACHED.withThreads(4);
System.out.println(PoolType.CACHED.getThreadsAmount()); // Prints 4
```

I would advise against it.

If you pass `PoolType.CACHED.withThreads(5)` to an `ExecutionStarter` and then `PoolType.CACHED.withThreads(4)` to another `ExecutionStarter`, if the first one gets threads amount via `getThreadsAmount()` later in time than the creation of the other, the first `ExecutionStarter` might also see a value of 4 instead of 5!

Comment: Now I see the mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Enum type is:
"An enum type is a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants..."

your approach seems unconventional.

I would use a factory/façade to pass the type/size parameters which will create a pool for me. 
The enum type seems redundant in this case.